# More than 1 question mark in java

Tags: java, recursion, conditional-operator

Iv'e searced google and didn't find my answer.
what does the "+"'s in the middle of the return means?
how can I "translate" this to "simple" if's and elses?
thanks!

```
return (j>0&&(mat[i+1][j-1]<mat[i][j]) ? countRopes(mat, i+1, j-1) : 0) +
    ((mat[i+1][j]<mat[i][j]) ? countRopes(mat, i+1, j) : 0) +
    (j<mat[0].length-1&&(mat[i+1][j+1]<mat[i][j]) ? countRopes(mat, i+1, j+1) : 0);
```

Comment: Beyond: the real take away: never ever write such code! People writing such code ... deserve their keyboard taken away; and a "no more code writing for you" ban ... for lengthy periods of time.

Comment: You can do this with an IDE that supports [refactoring](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit597-2005/Lectures/21-refactoring.ppt):. Extract Local Variable. If the IDE you are using doesn't support refactoring then it really doesn't support programming.

Answer (score 3):

That mysterious + sign is something mystical called an addition.

```
int result = 0;

if (j > 0 && mat[i+1][j-1]<mat[i][j]) {
    result = countRopes(mat, i+1, j-1);
}

if (math[i+1][j] < mat[i][j]) {
    result += countRopes(mat, i+1, j);
}

if (j < mat[0].length - 1 && math[i+1][j+1] < mat[i][j]) {
    result += countRopes (mat, i+1, j+1);
}

return result;
```

Comment: You want to point out that you are refactoring that ?: expression in there, to.

Comment: Why would I point out that I answered his question in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Do the various parentheses evaluate to the same data type?

The +s returns

1. The various concatenated values if they are Strings.
2. The sum of the ASCII values of the characters if characters.
3. The mathematical sum if they are ints or floats.

Mark's answer seems right provided we are dealing with ints.